# microsoft graph group notebooks call fails with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

Our web app has delagated `Notes.ReadWrite.All` permission, but for perticular client follwing call to

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/:groupid/onenote/notebooks
```

is returning `401 Unauthorized`

User is member of that group and can access **Group Notebooks** using `sharepoint` site

**Edit:**

Requested permissions are (all dlegeated)

`Mail.Send, User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read, Group.ReadWrite.All, Mail.ReadWrite, Tasks.ReadWrite, Calendars.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite, Notes.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All`

**Edit 2**
Call to `Group OneDrive` works from our app

call to `group onenote notebook` fails with `401`,
call to `personal onenote notebook` fails with `404`

All calls are from our application only

Comment: Have you received Admin Consent for the permission scopes? Could you also provide the complete list of scopes you've requested?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur added list of permissions

Comment: Are they able to access notebooks in other locations? Is this just one group or any group in the organization?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur AFAIK it is happening with all groups

Comment: What about other location?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I don't understand what is 'other location'?

Comment: Are you able to access notebooks in other locations (i.e. their own OneDrive)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I have to ask customer about this.I will get back to on tommorrow

Comment: @MarcLaFleur got back from customer.
Onedrive calls works,
onenote call fails for both group and personal notebooks,
Added more info in question itself.

Comment: @marcLaFleur: 
correction: it does NOT seem like Onedrive calls work either. Seem to get this response when trying to add a document to OneDrive using the API's:
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied
object Object Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Comment: It sounds like there is something specific to their tenant that is blocking you. Since fixing a single tenant's configuration will likely require deeper investigation, I'd suggest opening a support ticket with Microsoft directly. I'm afraid there are just too many potential variables and the support folks will have more granular insights into the setup than the community.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @MarcLaFleur. This supports my theory as a well, as we haven't seen this behavior with any other clients. We'll support our customer in bringing this to Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

Is this issue only for one client?

You might need Group scopes as well. 
Please refer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#group-permissions

Comment: By one client, I mean one organization
It works fine for our other clients(read organization/tenant), ithink its a issue with group policy, but i couln't find any documentaion